# How to add a background video view behind a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a login flow that has a video playing in the background, and pages of text on top of that fixed video, and the final page is the login form.

I've managed to build the page scroll, but each page has its own background and I'm kinda lost to find out how to make a view fixed with a looping video on bg, and transparent pages scrolling horizontally on top of that.

**UPDATE**

My storyboard is like this:
[image: storyboard]
And my BootViewController is implementing page handlers.

```
import UIKit

class BootViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    dataSource = self

    setViewControllers([UIStoryboard(name: "Boot", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: pages[0])], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

let pages = [
    "IntroPageOne",
    "IntroPageTwo",
    "LoginController"
]

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentViewControllerIdentifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier

    var previousViewController = pages.index(of: currentViewControllerIdentifier!)! - 1

    if previousViewController < 0 {
        previousViewController = pages.count - 1
    }

    let previousViewControllerIdentifier = pages[previousViewController]


    return UIStoryboard(name: "Boot", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: previousViewControllerIdentifier)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentViewControllerIdentifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier

    var nextViewController = pages.index(of: currentViewControllerIdentifier!)! + 1

    if nextViewController < 0 {
        nextViewController = 0
    }

    if nextViewController >= pages.count {
        nextViewController = 0
    }

    let nextViewControllerIdentifier = pages[nextViewController]


    return UIStoryboard(name: "Boot", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: nextViewControllerIdentifier)
}
}
```

I'm lost on how to create a subview and add (link) to my bootController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you just try the following setup?

```
UIViewController.view
  - backgroundVideoView
  - pageViewController.view
     - page1
     - page2
     ...
```

In this you add a background video view as a bottom view in `view.subviews`, and then you add a `view` of a pageViewController above it. All that you would need is to set `pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear` and `page1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`, etc., to make sure that the background is visible.

**UPDATE**

In your case, maybe something like this will be ok:

```
class BackgroundViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var pageViewController: BootViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // configure here anything with the video that you have to configure

        pageViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Boot", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BootViewController") as! BootViewController
        self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

        // set the frame, or use autolayout.. I will set the frame directly since it's easier here
        pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    }
}
```

There is no "backgroundView" of the `UIPageViewController`. To get something similar, you will use a different view controller to which you can include the view of your `UIPageViewController`. Then this parent view controller can become the background, and the page controller the foreground (because it is added as a topmost subview of the viewController).

Comment: I was thinking of that, got lost in the middle. DO I need more than 2 controllers to do that? The backgroundViewController to set the video on BG, and the pageViewController to add the bgView as subview and methods to handle the pages?

Comment: @Perdona where in the middle? update your question to include the code you already have.. and specify what is the problem with that code

Comment: Nosal I've update the question and my answer to you as well... Thanks for helping

Comment: @Perdona your `BootViewController` is a subclass of a pageViewController.. that means that in that you are at level of `pageViewController.view` from my suggested hierarchy. Try to include `BootViewController`'s view to the `backgroundView`'s view.. Show implementation of the `backgroundView`

Comment: this is where I'm getting lost. Implementation of `backgroundView` is blank. Since I'm new on swift, I'm getting trouble on how to actually set the hierarchy, by that I mean where and in which controller should I add reference? And how to link the views to controllers and other controllers..

Comment: @Perdona you are saying that you got pageViewController working,right? also, the video background is working, right? the only problem is how to put it together. include your code of the `backgroundView` controller.. that's where  I would start

Comment: No, the `videoBackground` is not implemented yet, so I only got the `pageViewController` working. But I'll melt harder here to find the right way to do so... But suppose I have a `backgroundView` with it's controller (should be a ViewController or UIView??) working... How do I reference and set this as the bg view of my `pageViewController` ?

Comment: @Perdona There is no "backgroundView" of the UIPageViewController. Therefore you have to set that hierarchy.. check my updated answer - in that I assume that `BackgroundViewController` is the view controller in which you have video playing. To that view add that page controller as a subview - it will be rendered above all the content (because its view is the last subview)